# Is the rails console dynamic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

is the console in rails (`~ rails c`) dynamic? For example; if I open the console and then make changes to a model will it pick these changes up or do I have to exit out of the console and run `rails c` again for it to pick up the changes in the model?

Comment: As Ryan points out, you need to call reload! to reload changes. You should also note that some changes require you to exit and relaunch the console. These changes include stuff like updating your config or environment files (I'm not sure what the full list is.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You will need to call the `reload!` method in the console to reload the changes. This method's magic is automatically called by `rails server` in development mode.

As a comment's pointed out beneath and another answer here, if you change things to do with the *environment* of the application, such as adding new gems to the `Gemfile`, making changes to anything in `config` or adding a new plugin then you'll need to restart the console. Any changes to `app` will be reloadable with `reload!`

If you were using this particular way to test that a method was working, I wouldn't. Tests (as in, the Test::Unit or RSpec) variants are much nicer because you have a reproducible way of running them again and again. `rails console` is great for one-off testing, but if you want to write a maintainable application then write tests.

Comment: If you change your gems or plugins, you'll need to exit and relaunch console; `reload!` doesn't cover these types of things.

Comment: Here is one case that is not evident. Let's say f is an instance of class Foo. If you change Foo, type `reload!`, and even `f.reload`, f.bar still will not have updated. You need to do reassign Foo. At least, that is how it works for me on OS X Lion using RVM on Ruby 1.9.3p125 and Rails 3.2.0.

Comment: @Aaron, `f` is in memory so it won't change even if you change its data in the database until you reassign it.